# How can I install GCC compiler in Fedora without internet?

Tags: gcc, installation, fedora-21

I got a new Fedora machine some time ago from this link http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/21/Workstation/i386/iso/Fedora-Live-Workstation-i686-21-5.iso. I need to install software, but for that I need a compiler ("No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH.") So, I want to install GCC compiler. I cannot connect to internet on the Fedora machine, but I do have an internet connected Windows 8.1 machine, that I can use to download and copy files via 2gb flash drive. Please help me on how to go about installing GCC to the Fedora machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the packages you need from the [Fedora mirrors](https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/) on your flash drive, you can install them on the command line with (for example)

```
 yum install /media/pathname/gcc-4.8.2-1.fc20.i686.rpm
```

However, since 2GB isn't big enough to include the entire Fedora release, you will need to pick and choose the packages. And this will leave you in the state we used to call "RPM hell" back before yum came along and solved that. You can either figure out the dependencies one by one (start with the above, and then add anything it tells you it is missing), or, you could go all out and copy the entire mirror in 2GB sized chunks to your Fedora machine's hard drive so you have it for any future needs.